# Why does the SqlPublish target fail for a SQL Server 2014 database project?

Tags: msbuild, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2014

My machine has the current (March 2014) version of SSDT, Visual Studio 2012 Professional, and SQL Server 2014 Developer. I have a SQL Server project (let's call it `MyProject.sqlproj`) that targets SQL Server 2014. I attempted the following:

```
MsBuild.exe MyProject.sqlproj 
            /t:SqlPublish /p:SqlPublishProfilePath=Somewhere.publish.xml
```

This fails with the following error:

> Deploy error Deploy 72002: Internal Error.
>   The database platform service with type
>   Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql120DatabaseSchemaProvider is not
>   valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide
>   the full type name of a valid database platform service.

If I switch this project to target 2012 (and point to a 2012 instance), this same command runs successfully. I had previously asked a potentially related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23375748/466874), and the answer there resolved my problem then, but that's not the issue here -- I'm able to publish this 2014 DACPAC successfully if I use `SqlPackage.exe` directly.

What's happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you running MSBuild from the VS2012 developer command prompt, or from a regular command prompt / some other environment? Also do you have VS2010 installed on your machine?

The most likely cause is that the VisualStudioVersion environment variable isn't set, in which case the .sqlproj file currently defaults to targeting the VS2010 version. Try calling "set VisualStudioVersion=11.0" before running MSBuild and see if this fixes the issue.

Comment: Aha! Yes, I do have VS 2010 installed, and was running it from a regular command prompt. Calling "set VisualStudioVersion=11.0" before executing it worked!

Comment: Great, problem solved :)

Comment: Thanks @KevinCunnane -- if you want to add this as an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that the VisualStudioVersion environment variable isn't set, in which case the .sqlproj file currently defaults to targeting the VS2010 version (which does not support SQL Server 2014). Calling "set VisualStudioVersion=11.0" before running MSBuild will fix the issue.

Comment: I have the same problem i think, I am using SQL Server 2012 Express on local and SQL Server 2008 on remote. I am developing and trying to publish Asp.net MVC 5 project. Everything was fine while i am using VS2013 . After upgrading to VS2015 i am starting to get the same error. Where can i change the VisualStudioVersion environment  ?

Comment: Where can we set the `VisualStudioVersion` variable, rather than setting it in the command line before running the MSBuild?