# The data type could not be assigned to the column "GeoLocation"

Tags: sql, azure

I want to take live database from Azure and copy it into my local SQL Server Management Studio 2014...

---

When i try importing from the live server, i see the db and select it, then i hit next and pick my local db and it throws:

---

```
TITLE: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard


Column information for the source and the destination data could not be retrieved, or the data types of source columns were not mapped correctly to those available on the destination provider.


[dbo].[Fields] -> [dbo].[Fields]:

          - The data type could not be assigned to the column "GeoLocation" in "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server".

[dbo].[FieldWanteds] -> [dbo].[FieldWanteds]:

          - The data type could not be assigned to the column "GeoLocation" in "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assign something to a field defined as `GeoLocation` that is not a GeoLocation value. The data types of `[dbo].[Fields]` and `[dbo].[FieldWanteds]` in your local DB that you are copying to are not GeoLocation. Check these fields and ensure the types match those in your Azure database.

Comment: Thanks, i ran my migrations to create the tables first then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQLPackage.exe to load your bacpac from the command-line like so:

`'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe' 
/a:Import /sf:z:\downloads\foo.bacpac 
/tsn:sql.example.com /tdn:foo /tu:USERNAME /tp:PASSWORDHERE`

I'm using SQL Server 2012, the exact location of the `.exe` might vary on a SQL 2014 according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375748/publish-dacpac-to-sql-server-2014-using-sqlpackage-exe).